# ui-sref or href in Ion-slide is not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to use ui-sref in ion-slide tag but it is not working.
Does ion-slide support ui-sref or href?

Please see the below code snippet

```
<ion-content scroll="false" class="animate-ripple">
    <ion-slide-box show-pager="false" ion-slide-tabs slide-tabs-scrollable=false on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
        <ion-slide ion-slide-tab-label="General" ui-sref="app.holiday.generalholiday"><ion-nav-view name="general-tab"></ion-nav-view></ion-slide>
        <ion-slide ion-slide-tab-label="Restricted" ui-sref="app.holiday.restrictedholiday"><ion-nav-view name="restricted-tab"></ion-nav-view></ion-slide>
        <ion-slide ion-slide-tab-label="On Sunday" ui-sref="app.holiday.onsundayholiday"><ion-nav-view name="onsunday-tab"></ion-nav-view></ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
</ion-content>
```

my app.js looks like below

```
$stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: "/app",
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
            controller: "AppCtrl"
        })

        .state('login', {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
            controller: "LoginCtrl"
        })

        .state('app.applyleave', {
            url: '/applyleave',
            views: {
                menuContent: {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/applyleave.html',
                    controller: 'ApplyLeaveCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.balances', {
            url: '/balances',
            views: {
                menuContent: {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/balances.html',
                    controller: 'BalancesCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.history', {
            url: '/history',
            views: {
                menuContent: {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/history.html',
                    controller: 'HistoryCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.holiday', {
            url: '/holiday',
            views: {
                menuContent: {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/holiday.html',
                    controller: 'HolidayCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.holiday.generalholiday', {
            url: '/generalholiday',
            views: {
                'general-tab': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/generalholiday.html',
                    controller: 'GeneralHolidayCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.holiday.restrictedholiday', {
            url: '/restrictedholiday',
            views: {
                'restricted-tab': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/restrictedholiday.html',
                    controller: 'RestrictedHolidayCtrl'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.holiday.onsundayholiday', {
            url: '/onsundayholiday',
            views: {
                'onsunday-tab': {
                    templateUrl: 'templates/onsundayholiday.html',
                    controller: 'SundayHolidayCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
```

Neither ui-sref nor href is working.
Please suggest if there is any workaround or I am missing something.

Comment: it wouldn't make sense for the *entire* slide element to be clickable, since it is dragable; you should be able to add a child element to the slide element that is clickable, though....

Comment: you could add `ng-click`` event and pass the state name in that event so that you could easily redirect to state using `$state.go`

Comment: ui-sref won't work , look https://github.com/JKnorr91/ion-slide-box-tabs/issues/4

Comment: Thanks for ur comments. Have figured that out and done the changes accordingly to get the desired output. I replaced my html in place of ion-nav view and on slide changed changed the scope variable to get the desired output. Ran into another problem though ion-slide-box tabs are not responsive.